# Use python to read a binary file(.NBF) and decode, chardet.dect used

Tags: python

I have a sound recording data which is saved in a binary file (.NBF) and I am trying to decode it in Python. However, the decoded contents are some random symbols, not the contents I expected. I've tried to use chardet.detect to find the encoding standard. However, I still get similar random symbols.  FYI: When I used their software to load this file, a doungle is required.

```
    while True:
        line = nbfFile.readline()
        if not line: 
            break
        print(line) # output b'\x03\x0f\x00....
        print(chardet.detect(line)) # output encoding: ISO-8859-1, confidenc: 0.73
        aa = codecs.decode(line, 'ISO-8859-1')
        print(aa) # output some random symbols
```

Expected output:

```
Delimiter:      
File version    v1.0/5.0.1.10
Filename    FileName.NBF (FileName)
...

Primary reverberation time -    T20
Frequency (Hz)  T20 mean (sec)  Status  T20 stdev (sec)
50 Hz   0.59    ?
63 Hz   0.60
...
```

Comment: Why do you expect that output? It's a binary file right? Not text. Also if it requires a dongle to load in their software, it could also be encrypted

Comment: The kind of encodings you are trying to use are well-known and well-understood ways of representing non-ascii Unicode characters in bytestrings. You seem to be expecting that `codecs.decode()` can be persuaded to decode any arbitrary encryption scheme. It can't. And `chardet` is unlikely to be any help because all it is trying to do is match the data it sees to the codecs it knows about. 73% is fairly close to total failure. There is no magic bullet here. You are going to have to read the data with and without the dongle and try and figure out the encryption scheme for yourself.

Comment: Thank you both.  Should I contact the software own to see whether they could provide help?

Comment: Absolutely, yes, if that's an option.